# Least CPU intensive way to get number of matching elements?

Tags: templating, sql

Which is the least CPU intensive (SQL-intensive) way to get the sum of products that are `relatedTo` a category?

Like this?

`{% set productCount = craft.products.relatedTo(category)|length %}`

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the |length twig filter you are implicitly treating the element query as an array. 
This behaviour was depreciated in Craft 3, and also results in a DB query being sent that is equivalent to .count() (Craft 3) or .total() (Craft 2).

To remain up to date, while still minimising SQL load for your page: either call the relevant command (.count(), .total()):

```
{% set productCount = craft.products.relatedTo(category).count() %}
```

Or, if you're going to be doing a full (limit: null) query at some point anyway, do that now and then use the length filter:

```
{% set products = craft.products.relatedTo(category).limit(null).all() %}
{% set productCount = products|length %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Nick.